# AngularJS animation using ng-view and UI Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a rather unusual situation in which I am using the tabs from UI Bootstrap and want a fade out/fade in animation when each tab is clicked. What makes it unusual is that the tab contents are not all included on the same page, but are separate views. I am really just after the visual effect of the tabs, which I guess I could get by other means but there you go. An example view looks like this:

```
<div>
    <tabset>
        <tab heading="Enquiries" select="enquiriesSelected()"></tab>
        <tab heading="Airlines" select="airlinesSelected()"></tab>
        <tab heading="Aircraft" select="aircraftSelected()"></tab>
        <tab heading="Airports" select="airportsSelected()"></tab>
        <tab heading="Customers" active="true">
            <!-- tab content, other tab contents are empty -->
        </tab>
    </tabset>
</div>
```

My controller behaviour looks like this:

```
$scope.enquiriesSelected = function() {
    $location.path("/enquiries");
};
```

and my CSS looks like this:

```
.view-fade.ng-enter {
  transition: all 1s ease;
  -webkit-transition:all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
}

.view-fade.ng-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}

.view-fade.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.view-fade.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  opacity:1;
}

.view-fade.ng-leave{
  opacity:0;
}
```

Finally, my class is applied in HTML like this:

```
<div ng-view class="view-fade container" />
```

This all works as expected, except for one thing. When clicking on a tab header, the current tab and its content disappear completely before the new one gradually fades in. What I would like is for the current tab to fade out so that the tab headers themselves never appear to disappear from view, if you see what I mean!

Is this possible? I expect it's a fiddling-with-the-css job rather than any functional change, but this is my first AngularJS project that uses animation and I'm a bit stuck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I understand correctly this should solve your problem
http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/12/staggering-animations-in-angularjs.html

Comment: That's not exactly what I meant, no. If you take a look at http://dfsq.github.io/ngView-animation-effects and execute the fade in/fade out transition, the previous view remains behind the new one so that they are both briefly visible simultaneously. In my case, the previous view is disappearing completely while the new one fades in.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Some bad CSS. Here's the working version:

```
.view-fade.ng-enter, .view-fade.ng-leave {
    transition: all 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition:all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
}

.view-fade.ng-enter {
    opacity: 0;
}
.view-fade.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
}
.view-fade.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
    opacity:0;
}
.view-fade.ng-leave {
    opacity:1;
}
```

Now I have a (slightly) another problem in that the content is appearing lower down then jumping up when the animation finishes. I think I can fix this.

**UPDATE**

I fixed the jumping problem. Needed to add this CSS:

```
.view-fade {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Happy bunny now!